# Apex Test class (Field is not writeable: CampaignMember.RecordTypeId)

Tags: apex, unit-test, record-type

I really am not sure what I am doing wrong here but I am being thrown the error I am doing exactly what I have read to do on stackoverflow and in the SF docs. Any ideas?:

> Field is not writeable: CampaignMember.RecordTypeId (Line: 7, Column: 11)

```
@isTest
private class TestCampaignMemberTrigger {
    @isTest
    static void test_method_one() {
        CampaignMember cmPhone = new CampaignMember();
        Id phone = Schema.SObjectType.CampaignMember.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Fundraising_Dinners').getRecordTypeId();
        cmPhone.RecordTypeId=phone;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_campaignmember.htm) about `RecordTypeId` field on `CampaignMember` says:

> ID of the record type assigned to this object. To change the record
>   type, modify the CampaignMemberRecordTypeId field on the associated
>   Campaign.

so you can't assign record type to `CampaignMember` record in this way.
Select related `Campaign` and change `CampaignMemberRecordTypeId` field